# Is it correct to include 3 non-independent proportions of time (counts of video frames) in a glmm to compare them?

Tags: r, regression, binomial-distribution, proportion, glmm

In my team, we have an experiment where we record each individual in an arena that has 3 separate areas (lets say A, B and C). We have two conditions (let's call them condition 1 and condition 2). Individuals are split in 2 groups, one starting with condition 1 and finishing with condition 2 while the second group does the opposite.

My colleague organized the data as follows (example for two individuals):

[image]

My colleague proposes to analyze it with a GLMM. To see the effect of the condition on the proportion spent in each area, the model below was used in R:

```
glmer(cbind(Frames,TotalFrames-Frames)~Area*Condition+(1|Individual), family=binomial(link = "logit"))
```

R gives a warning for singularity when we run this model:

```
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

My colleague mentioned that it may come from the random effect and ran a GLM instead, which did not give any singularity warning.

On the other hand, I was worried that the problem comes from the fact that the proportions of time spent in each area by each individual are not independent from each other, because one individual cannot be in two areas at the same time. Indeed, when I remove one of the 3 areas from the dataset (making the two areas left in the analysis less dependent on each other), the singularity warning disappears.

Thus, I am wondering if it is correct to compare non-independent proportions of time like my colleague suggested. If so, why do we have the singularity warning (is it really due to the random effect) and is it a problem?

---

To put my mind at ease, I guess I have to simplify my question: so let's imagine that we flip several coins multiple times.

Is it correct to use a GLM to compare
proportions of heads/tails to proportions of tails/heads to conclude that we have significantly more heads than tails.

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is indeed enough random variation between subjects? Your random effects as modeled do not indicate any extreme complexity which would normally create this error, but you may simply not have enough random variance per individual to need a mixed model.

Comment: Thank you @ShawnHemelstrand for your answer. Actually the GLMM gives a random effect variance of exactly 0 (std dev=0 too). Isn't that suspicious? However, if I run the same model with one of the 3 areas excluded from the dataset, the variance of the random effect becomes non-null and the singularity warning disapears.

Comment: Typically low random effects variance is whats causes a singular matrix, but estimates from the summary will anyway be unreliable with it being singular. You can check by-subject scatter plots to see if they vary to be sure.